# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to have a code that does the following:

```
#create a new column in a dataframe 
df['new_column'] = 0
```

and for every row in this dataframe, it looks at whether column B's value is 1. If it is, it populates the new column with a 1, it then jumps 126 rows forward, and populates that row of the new column with a -1; otherwise, it populates the row of the new column with a 0. Once done that, the formula should continue from a row that would depend on the value encountered in the column B (i.e., if in the first iteration, column B's value=1, the row from which the loop restarts will be 127, alternatively it would be row 2)

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    for item in df['new_column']:
        if df.B[df.new_column[df.new_column.index[item]]] == 1:
            item = 1
            row += 126
            item = -1
        else:
            item = 0
```

Problem is that I get: "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple". Could you please help me?

Comment: You're looking for `df_zing.iterrows()`.